# git checkout with a variable that has multiple files in it

Tags: git, shell, variables, sh, git-checkout

I have a use-case for checking out multiple files whos name are in a variable. The piece of code that i written is:

```
b="file1 file2"
git checkout origin/branch1 $b
```

While executing this code i am getting error as :

```
error: pathspec 'file1 file2' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

if i give the file name directly like `git checkout origin/branch1 file1 file2` its working fine also, if  their is only one file name in the variable its also working fine.

i use shell for writing the code

Kindly please suggest me a way to pass multiple file names that are in a variable for checking out file.

Comment: This looks like what would happen if you wrote `"$b"` (quoted), are you sure you didn't quote `$b`?

Comment: Also, which shell exactly are you using?

Comment: @BenjaminW.i am sure i am using $b . the variable b has 3 filename that need to be checked out. for testing purpose i am using git cli and sh

Comment: What's the output of `echo $0`? What OS are you working in?

Comment: echo $0 displayed nothing. I am working on windows 10

Comment: It looks like word splitting doesn't happen, where in native Bash it would. What terminal emulator are you using? Are you running this with `cmd.exe`, or mintty?

Comment: as i have git cli i am using that. from the git cli i am running the script

Comment: I jest tried the above script in azure devops bash script also, but got same error

Comment: Standard POSIX shells do word-splitting on `$IFS` after expanding variables. Are you using a standard POSIX shell? If so, have you altered `$IFS` from its usual space-tab-newline setting?

Comment: If one file is okay, try the workaround `for f in $b;do git checkout origin/branch1 $f;done`.

Comment: Hi @torek i have altered the IFS="," at the beginning, is that what will cause the issue?

Comment: @SebastianPeter: yes, that would do it. With IFS set to just a comma, the variable would have to contain `file1,file2` as its value to pass `file1` and `file2` as two separate arguments.

Comment: @torek thank you very much. the solution you provided resolved my issue.

Comment: If `IFS` was the issue, then I'd close as "can't be reproduced" based on what was provided.

Comment: @Benjamin ok you can close this thanks for your support.